# Is it OK to name a subclass same as parent?

Tags: python, inheritance

Is this OK?

```
class JSONEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
```

Then I can use my JSONEncoder class instead of the one from `json`.

Comment: If the very point of the same-named class is a drop-in replacement for a different class, it's OK. Otherwise, it's likely a bad idea, _because_ it will work, and one class may shadow another in the same namespace.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, that will work.

However, if someone does:

```
from json import *
from <yourmodule> import *
```

then the names will clash and the last one imported will win, which won't mess up your library but maybe their code.

Comment: Yeah, I suppose. But if this is a fully private module, then it is fine, right?

Comment: ATOzTOA: It will work, but it's generally considered a bad practice because of potential confusion and the fact that you're replacing a standard item with a custom one.